# Customizing Tags in SendGrid Node Module

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send automated thank you emails using the SendGrid NodejS module.  In the text field I would like to add the person's full name which I have stored as a variable.  When I put the variable in the text field it fails.  I would think the bottom use case is correct but it keeps failing.

```
var email = new sendgrid.Email({
    to: customerEmail,
    toname: fullName,
    fromname: 'Treasurer',
    from: 'treasurer@shalomravaustin.com',
    subject: 'Payment Confirmed',
    text: 'Hello' + ' ' + fullName + ' ' + Thanks for paying online'
});
```

Comment: In send method, do you get any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed one of single qoute in text field just before thanks.

it should be 
text: 'Hello' + ' ' + fullName + ' ' + 'Thanks for paying online'

Apart from this, I don't think there is any error. and also check if FullName variable is not empty.